# Eloquent groupBy but only group ONE row

Tags: php, eloquent

I need to group the following rows based on the type, but I need the Collection to just have the item and not an array with 1 item inside it.

Example database rows:

```
id     location_id      type      section_id       content
0          2          telephone        1          123135145
1          2           mobile          1          245446546
```

Expected Result:

```
[
    'telephone' => [
        'id' => 0,
        'location_id' => 2,
        'type' => 'telephone',
        'section_id' => 1,
        'content' => 123135145
    ],
    'mobile' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'location_id' => 2,
        'type' => 'mobile',
        'section_id' => 1,
        'content' => 245446546
    ]
]
```

Actual Result:

```
[
    'telephone' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 0,
            'location_id' => 2,
            'type' => 'telephone',
            'section_id' => 1,
            'content' => 123135145
        ]
    ],
    'mobile' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 1,
            'location_id' => 2,
            'type' => 'mobile',
            'section_id' => 1,
            'content' => 245446546
        ]
    ]
]
```

Here is my Eloquent query

```
$contactDetails = $this->contactDetails()->where([ 'section_id' => 1 ])->get()->groupBy('type');
```

The `contactDetails()` method is relationship:

```
public function contactDetails(){

    return $this->hasMany(WebsiteLocationContactDetails::class);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an eloquent expert but I think this result is correct and that you should simply adjust the result after you get it.

Try it with [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$array%20=%20[%5Cn%20'telephone'%20=%3E%20[%5Cn%200%20=%3E%20[%5Cn%20'id'%20=%3E%200,%5Cn%20'location_id'%20=%3E%202,%5Cn%20'type'%20=%3E%20'telephone',%5Cn%20'section_id'%20=%3E%201,%5Cn%20'content'%20=%3E%20123135145%5Cn%20]%5Cn%20],%5Cn%20'mobile'%20=%3E%20[%5Cn%200%20=%3E%20[%5Cn%20'id'%20=%3E%201,%5Cn%20'location_id'%20=%3E%202,%5Cn%20'type'%20=%3E%20'mobile',%5Cn%20'section_id'%20=%3E%201,%5Cn%20'content'%20=%3E%20245446546%5Cn%20]%5Cn%20]%5Cn];%5Cnforeach($array%20as%20$k%20=%3E%20$v)%20%7B%5Cn%20$newArray[$k]%20=%20$v[0];%5Cn%7D%5Cnecho%20'%3Cpre%3E';%20print_r($newArray);%20echo%20'%3C/pre%3E';%5Cn?%3E%5Cn).

```
<?php
$array = [
    'telephone' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 0,
            'location_id' => 2,
            'type' => 'telephone',
            'section_id' => 1,
            'content' => 123135145
        ]
    ],
    'mobile' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 1,
            'location_id' => 2,
            'type' => 'mobile',
            'section_id' => 1,
            'content' => 245446546
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $newArray[$k] = $v[0];
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($newArray); echo '</pre>';
?>
```